# Legal aspects of the HackRF one / SDR in Switzerland?

Tags: legal, rf-power, hackrf, europe

I would like to know, what I can legally do with SDR / a Hack RF One in Switzerland?

What are the limitations concerning sending and receiving?

Do I need any licenses for that? If so, which ones, and for what are they usable?

Comment: The rest of this can really be better researched with google – "which amateur licenses exist" in your preferred language; I'd recommend asking questions here that can't be answered better by directly reading the [authorative sources](https://www.bakom.admin.ch/bakom/de/home/frequenzen-antennen/frequenznutzung-mit-oder-ohne-konzessionen/amateurfunk.html) :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Why don't you post that first comment as an answer?

Comment: Thank you, @MarcusMüller ! :-)

Comment: It will depend on the frequency in which you will transmit. I'm pretty sure in Switzerland too there will be some frequencies "open for everybody" (like those that your garage opener would use), some that will require a certain license, and others that will be a complete no-no.

Answer (score 3):

The device usually doesn't have anything to do with legality, it's what you do. So, rule of thumb: Without a license, you can't transmit – full stop.

I'm not quite sure about federal Swiss law, but chances are you can only receive broadcast transmissions (meant for everyone to receive) and transmissions especially meant for you, and everything else is eavesdropping / invasion of privacy. Amateur radio transmissions are by definition broadcast, so always OK to receive, but you can't transmit in these bands without an amateur license.

Comment: ["eidgenossenschaftliches" Translation](https://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/eidgenossenschaftlich.html)

Comment: @MikeWaters hahaha, ah that happens when you just copy and paste your own comment to an answer – the Eidgenossenschaft is the "Oath union", ie. the federal Swiss state, and "eidgenossenschaftlich" means "federal Swiss".